# Call SignalR Client Method on Startup

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I want to call a client side method from my SignalR hub class only once, when the client first loads up the webpage. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `BlahBlahHub` class, you have access to all of the connection methods that you do on the Client. Hint: Look at the base `Hub` class.

With that being said, here's what the code would look like:

### Hub

```
[HubName("messageHub")]
    public class MessageHub : Hub
    {
        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            Clients.Caller.alertUser(88);

            return base.OnConnected();
        }
    }
```

### Client

```
var sender = $.connection.messageHub;

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

}).fail(function (reason) {
    console.log("SignalR connection failed: " + reason);
});

sender.client.alertUser = function (test) {
    alert(test);
};
```

Comment: public override Task OnConnected() will  only be called when the user initially connects?

Comment: What do you mean 'initially' connects? And did you try the code? Does it work for your scenario?

Comment: So there's 2 ways to interpret your request. When a user establishes a connection with the SignalR Hub, or only when new users (aka users who have never connected to the hub before) connect to the Hub. In that case, you'd probably need a way to integrate with Redis/Service Bus/SQL Server to identify user's connections.

Comment: I meant when a user establishes a connection with the SignalR Hub, I figured it out though, thanks everyone